# One object per HttpContext instance

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unity-container, object-lifetime

I'm currently writing a project in ASP.NET MVC. I have a web project and DB project which solely works with DB. The layers look like this and they interoperate only with sibling layers.

**DB project (EF CF)**  - makes db requests

**Repository** - abstracting the underlying db model

**Service** - All business logic happenes here.

**ASP.NET MVC Web application** - Front end presentation

They must be loosely coupled so I'm using Unity DI/IoC framework

What I want to achieve is to create one instance of `DbContext` per http request. The following is the logic I implemented so far.

```
public class MyAppBaseController : Controller {
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) {
        if (HttpContext.Items["DbModel"] == null) {
            HttpContext.Items["DbModel"] = MySingleton.Container.Resolve<DbContext>();
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

What is does is that in request pipeline if the `Items` dictionary of the current `HttpContext` doesn't have `DbContext`, it adds one. All controllers inherit from it. The reason why I'm doing so is that all repositories that will be called during execution should use exactly the same `DbContext` object for all sequential db calls.

1. Is there a better way to couple the lifetime of the object with the `HttpContext`?
2. Is it possible to do it using Unity (DI/IoC framework)?

Comment: Why you don't use a member variable to store che DbContext instead of using the HttpContext.Items dictionary?

Comment: @Bugeo Can you be more specific and support it with code snippet?

Comment: https://github.com/ayende/TekPub.Profiler.BackOffice/blob/master/TekPub.Profiler.BackOffice/Controllers/RavenController.cs

Comment: @Bugeo Thank you but, in my case this is not suitable because in my application there are cases where several actions from different controllers are executed (via `Html.RenderAction()`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can take control over the instance lifetime of your dependencies in unity's object lifetime management as specified [here](http://www.ladislavmrnka.com/2011/03/unity-build-in-lifetime-managers/)

you will have to write your own that injects your object instance in httpcontext

Comment: Thank you for your link. Most likely I'll check out the `PerThreadLifetimeManager`. Most likely it will satisfy my requirements as all DB queries will be made in one thread.